# Do local field potentials (LFP) create waves on the surfaces of nerve cells?

Tags: neuroscience, biophysics, neuroanatomy, electrophysiology

Are waves created by the LFP on the surfaces of neurons cell bodies? Since the cells have a resting potential, do these waves create harmonic oscillation of the membranes at particular frequencies?

Are there studies available that look at electrical potential waves on the cell surfaces? I think that membranes should be sensitive to the LFP since they maintain a charge.

Answer (score 2):

A LFP can be measured at any point in space and is just the sum of all the fields generated by nearby charges.  Conventionally, it's assumed to be some distance from a cluster of neurons, but you technically could measure the LFP near the external surface of a neuron (but that would bias your signal towards the reading of that one neuron).

LFP's are relatively weak, but have some small influence on the neighboring cells:

[Modeling the coupling of single neuron activity to local field potentials](http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2202/10/S1/P291)